# JavaScript not recognizing longitude geocoordinates

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geocoding

I'm mostly a python developer but I'm trying my way in JavaScript and HTML for a university project. I'm using Leaflet to create a map and am currently trying to add some nodes to the map, using the coordinates, and subsequently adding edges to them. But for some reason it won't recognize the longitude. Here are my code and error:

1. HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.css" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body style="border:0; margin:0">
        <div id="mapid"></div>

        <div class="formBlock">
            <form id="form">
                <input type="text" name="start" class="input", id="start", placeholder="Choose starting point" />
                <input type="text" name="end" class="input", id="destination", placeholder="Choose Destination" />
                <button type="submit">Get Directions</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.2/mq-map.js?key=endTO6iFLU2paIdnoCnXHLCSYQX6ajFj"></script>
        <script src="https://www.mapquestapi.com/sdk/leaflet/v2.2/mq-routing.js?key=endTO6iFLU2paIdnoCnXHLCSYQX6ajFj"></script>
        <script src="/css/app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

2.JavaScript

```
var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([-22.899346, -43.413119], 13);


L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
    maxZoom: 18,
    id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
    tileSize: 512,
    zoomOffset: -1,
    accessToken: 'pk.eyJ1IjoidmljdG9yYm9tYmFyZGEiLCJhIjoiY2twNWgzZTdsMXhpcTJ2dGF6bjN6MXc5YiJ9.ZMzO1j4VVEjsLbf3MXnQWw'
    }).addTo(mymap);

    

var circle = L.circle([-22.9809493, -43.2068586], {
    color: 'red',
    fillColor: '#f03',
    fillOpacity: 0.5,
    radius: 500
}).addTo(mymap);
```

3. The error (from browser console):

```
>> Uncaught Error: invalid LatLng object (-22.9809493, NaN)
```

I'm lost and desperately looking for some help.

Comment: I'm just guessing: maybe that `radius` is also in degrees, so it covers the Earth several times over? Try with a smaller one (like 1) and see what happens.

Comment: I’m currently afk but as soon as I can I will try it. Any clue why NaN showing up? I tried it on another polygon creation, no radius, and same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the newest Leaflet Version `1.7.1`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.7.1/leaflet.css" /> 
<script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v1.7.1/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yeah, that was definitely the problem, thank you very much!